# Can't access to Google Firestore Emulator docker image from my api container

Tags: firebase, docker

I created a docker image for firebase emulators : `auth`, `firestore`, `database` and `storage` .
I am running  them in `0.0.0.0`
My issue is that I am not able to access to them from my api docker container ( I can access to them from local api)
The errors am having while trying to connect to emulators from my api docker image:

```
ERROR 14 UNAVAILABLE: No connection established
```

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION:**

To connect to `firebase` container from another container we should put the `HOST` of the firebase emulator in the other container (api for example) as the name of the firebase service in the `docker-compose` file.

Example if the firebase part of my `docker-compose` is like that :

```
  firebase:
    container_name: firebase-emulators
    image:firebase-emulators
    ports:
      - '9099:9099' # Auth
      - '8080:8080' # Firestore
      - '9000:9000' # Database
      - '9199:9199' # Storage
      - '4000:4000' # UI
```

In my `api` code  I should have :

```
process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST=firebase:9099
process.env.FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=firebase:8080
process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_EMULATOR_HOST=firebase:9000
process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_EMULATOR_HOST= firebase:9199
```